# Uncaught SyntaxError, Unexpected Identifier in for loop in jade

Tags: json, node.js, for-loop, express, pug

I am trying to render a jade with some dynamic content. I am reading from a json in jade.
My json looks like this

```
{ data1: 'data1',
  data2: 'data2',
  data3: 
 [ { name: 'ABC',
   address: 'India'
   },
   { name: 'DEF',
   address: 'Australia'
   }]}
```

I am trying to render a jade and use the data from above json
my jade looks like

```
  var data1 = #{data1};
  var data2 = #{data2};
  var size = #{data3.length};
  for data in #{data3}
    var name = data.name;
    var address = data.address;
```

I am able to correctly extract data in the first 3 lines mentioned above. But when I try to fetch data from within a loop, I get "Uncaught SyntaXError, Unexpected Identifier" error while debugging.
If i put a line outisde the for loop, it works fine. Ex

```
 var name = #{data3[0].name};
```

is rendered properly. But i need to iterate over a loop and fetch data over there. Can somebody help.
Thanks

Updating with more information
1. I have node server running where I create a json -

```
 var json_string = "{"data1":"data1","data2":"data2","data3":[{"name":"ABC","address":"India"},{"name":"DEF","address":"Australia"}]};";
 var json_data = JSON.parse(json_string);
 console.log(json_data);
 res.render('sample_example', json_data);
```

1. In my sample_example.jade I have the following snippet within script

   ```
     var data1 = #{data1};
     var data2 = #{data2};
     var size = #{data3.length};
     for data in #{data3}
       var name = data.name;
       var address = data.address;
   ```

As stated earlier, I am able to properly extract     #{data1},    #{data2},    #{data3.length} to the variables . But it breaks within the for loop. In fact, I am able to extract #{data3[0].name} from outside the for loop. But within the for looop it gives the stated error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it now.

In your server-side you have to `JSON.stringify` the array of objects.

```
var json_data = JSON.parse(json_string);

// Convert back to json only the property data3
json_data.data3 = JSON.stringify(json_data.data3);
res.render('simple', json_data);
```

Or the better is to not parse the JSON just let it go the way it is:

```
// var json_data = JSON.parse(json_string);
res.render('simple', {
  json_data: json_string
});
```

And in the Jade Template (If you followed the better method):

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  var json_data = !{json_data};
  var data1 = json_data.data1;
  var data2 = json_data.data2;
  var data3 = json_data.data3;
  var size = data3.length;

  data3.forEach(function(data) {
    var name = data.name;
    var address = data.address;
    console.log(name, address);
  });
```

Also you need to change the loop structure. The `for..in` used to iterate over objects not array of objects.

Comment: It does not work. I am using this within a script. and jade treats it as a variable instead of html element. I tried as suggested as well and I get "Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected token var".

Comment: @BKSingh Your JSON should be wrap with `'` single quotes, also make sure your indentation are proper.

Comment: This is how my html looks like
<script>var data1=data1;
var data2=data2;
var size = 2;
for data in [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: I am still stuck on this.. Is there a way to have multiple for each in single statement. 
I am now sending my data as {"name":["X","Y"], "address":["India","Aus"]}
I am able to iterate over them as "for data in name" or "for data in addess".... But I want them in a single loop instead of 2 loops

Answer (score 0):

This works for me;

```
- var cdata = {"data1":"data1","data2":"data2","data3":[{"name":"ABC","address":"India"},{"name":"DEF","address":"Australia"}]};
each data in cdata.data3
  - var name = data.name;
  - var address = data.address;
  p Name: #{name}
  p Address: #{address}
```

Can you share the actual jade file contents if updating the code as shown above doesn't work. Also what version of jade and express?

Comment: Does `for data in data3
  - var name = data.name;
  - var address = data.address;` (without the curly braces on `data3`) not work for you?

Comment: No it doesnt. I still get the error - "Unexpected Identifier"

Comment: I get ">" in the chrome debugger as well, after the line "uncaught syntax error...".. Not sure if that is something that is causing the issue